# Why does posh fail to perform pathname expansion when a part of the path is specified within double-quotes?

Tags: linux, shell, debian, posix

Consider the following simple shell script:

```
rm -rf bar \"bar\"
mkdir -p bar
touch bar/baz
echo "bar"/*
```

I get the expected output with bash, ksh, zsh and dash, but I don't get
it with posh:

```
susam@debian:~$ bash foo.sh
bar/baz
susam@debian:~$ ksh foo.sh
bar/baz
susam@debian:~$ zsh foo.sh 
bar/baz
susam@debian:~$ dash foo.sh
bar/baz
susam@debian:~$ posh foo.sh
bar/*
```

I am trying to understand if the behaviour of posh is correct as per the POSIX standard or if it is a bug.

The relevant section in the POSIX documents seem to be "2.6 Word Expansion":

- POSIX.1-2004: [2.6 Word Expansions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06)
- POSIX.1-2008: [2.6 Word Expansions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06)

Both of them mention that pathname expansion occurs before quote removal.

> 3. Pathname expansion (see *Pathname Expansion*) shall be performed, unless `set -f` is in effect.
> 4. Quote removal (see *Quote Removal*) shall always be performed last.

Considering this, the posh behaviour looks right because `"bar"/*` does not literally match any path above before the quote removal, so path expansion does not occur.

So this led me to suspect that if there were a directory literally named `"bar"`, i.e. the quotes were part of the directory name, then posh would have matched it. But the following altered script shows that this is not true.

```
rm -rf bar \"bar\"
mkdir -p \"bar\"
touch \"bar\"/baz
echo "bar"/*
```

Here is the output:

```
susam@debian1:~$ bash foo2.sh 
bar/*
susam@debian1:~$ ksh foo2.sh 
bar/*
susam@debian1:~$ zsh foo2.sh 
foo2.sh:3: no matches found: bar/*
susam@debian1:~$ dash foo2.sh 
bar/*
susam@debian1:~$ posh foo2.sh 
bar/*
```

So the pattern `"bar"/*` in posh matches neither the path `bar/baz` nor the path `"bar"/baz`. What does it match then? Is the posh behaviour a bug or a feature?

Here are the version details in case it helps you to helps me:

```
susam@debian:~$ cat /etc/debian_version 
8.3
susam@debian:~$ dpkg -l bash ksh zsh dash posh
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                        Version            Architecture       Description
+++-===========================-==================-==================-============================================================
ii  bash                        4.3-11+b1          amd64              GNU Bourne Again SHell
ii  dash                        0.5.7-4+b1         amd64              POSIX-compliant shell
ii  ksh                         93u+20120801-1     amd64              Real, AT&T version of the Korn shell
ii  posh                        0.12.3             amd64              Policy-compliant Ordinary SHell
ii  zsh                         5.0.7-5            amd64              shell with lots of features
```

Comment: For a question of whether a feature of `posh` is POSIX compliant, results from `zsh` and `bash` aren't relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a bug in `posh`** -- see bug [#636601](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=636601). It is still open as of `posh` version 0.12.6.

Attached to the [discussion](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=636601) of that bug you'll find a [patch](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=1;bug=636601;filename=posh-quote.patch;msg=30). When applying that, `posh` behaves similar to `bash` (so in your first example `echo "bar"/*` gives `bar/baz`).

Furthermore, that behaviour of **`bash` (and *patched* `posh`) does conform to POSIX**. The standard says

> 4. Quote removal (see Quote Removal) shall always be performed last.

This is meant ***literally***, as a *purely syntactical* action to remove protective quotes in the very last step. The *semantical* meaning of quotes will still apply in earlier steps, as pointed out by hek2mgl. (Otherwise, e.g. a quotation like `"*"` would not have any effect at all.)

So on second thought, this conclusion is not correct:

> Considering this, the posh behaviour looks right because "bar"/* does
>   not literally match any path above before the quote removal, so path
>   expansion does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Even before [quote removal](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quote-Removal.html) the shell will treat unquoted `"` as string delimiters not as literal chars.

Furthermore I can't reproduce your test results. In both cases bash and posh gave the same results for me.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. Given a file `bar/baz` (no quotes in names), `echo "bar"/*` matches the file in bash/ksh/zsh/dash. But it does not in posh. The first two code snippets in my question shows the issue. The remainder of the question is my own commentary on the issue.

Comment: I've just executed your second example in bash and my results were not the same as yours. So there is already something wrong with your results. Also, as I said. The `"` aren't treated as literally `"`, even before word splitting.

Comment: To be clear bash reveals in both cases the same results as posh for me. Back soon if something is still unclear

Comment: You get the same output `bar/baz` in the second example because in the second example the pattern `"bar"/*` matches the file `bar/baz` created by the first example. If you `rm -rf bar` before running the second example, you should be able to reproduce the same results I have, i.e. the pattern `"bar"/*` would not match the path `"bar"/baz` because this time we have literal quotes in the directory name. I have updated both my examples in the question to `rm -rf bar \"bar\"` so that the examples run in a clean environment and the first example does not affect the output of the second example.

Comment: Again, same results with `bash` and `posh` on my side. Sorry, I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: Could you please share the bash and posh version numbers you have? I am considering the possibility that this was a bug that may have been fixed in a later version.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too. I'm using `GNU bash, Version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` and `posh 0.12.5`

Answer (score -2):

You can try with `bash --posix` (to have a POSIX behaviour) and you will see that the result is `bar/baz`.

The point is that the the pathname expansion of "bar" gives `bar`. See SCL section 2.13 for more details on the pattern matching un truc th name expansion.

Comment: I don't understand which part of the question is your answer addressing. In the first example, `bash foo.sh` produces the output `bar/baz` even without the `--posix` option. In the second example, both `bash foo2.sh` and `bash --posix foo2.sh` produce the output `bar/*`. So why exactly do you want to add the `--posix` option? Yes, the pattern `"bar"` matches the path `bar` and this is already demonstrated in my question. What are you trying to add to what I have already mentioned in the question?

Comment: Also, my question is about the behaviour of `posh`, not that of `bash`. In particular, my question is, `So the pattern "bar"/* in posh matches neither the path bar/baz nor the path "bar"/baz. What does it match then? Is the posh behaviour a bug or a feature?`

Comment: In your question you ask if the posh behavior is POSIX compliant. So I suggested to test with `bash --posix` instead of `bash`.

Comment: Yes you demonstrated that "bar" matches bar but I explained that is the behavior described in the SCL. So I don't see any good reason why posh would deliberately not follow this which is followed by all other common shells.